# Which key is KEY_LEFT_GUI?

Tags: arduino-micro, atmega32u4

This might be a very simple question but I don't know which key represents KEY_LEFT_GUI on my keyboard. I thought it was the windows key but when I program Arduino Micro to execute it. Run does not open and it prints powershell on the "Search Programs and Files" section in Windows7 VM.

```
  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.press('r');
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();

  delay(500);

  Keyboard.print("powershell");
  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KEY_LEFT_GUI is the left Windows key. I think the problem may be that your code is only holding those keys down for microseconds. You need to give the computer a little bit of time to recognize the keypresses because it's expecting a human using a keyboard, not a microcontroller running at 16MHz. Try adding a delay before `Keyboard.releaseAll();`.

Comment: it's still just opening the start menu and typing it there instead of opening run I added a 1000 delay before releaseAll and a 1000 delay above press('r') but it is only detecting the windows press not the r

Comment: I guess I just didn't know how fast a millisecond really is. I changed the delay to 4000 and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer, but you can use to open the run window:

Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  Keyboard.press(114);
  Keyboard.releaseAll();

And yes, as per1234 says, KEY_LEFT_GUI is the left windows key